# Send file from backend (NodeJS) to frontend (angular)

Tags: node.js, angular, docker-compose

I am generating a PDF file in my backend. The generated file is stored in Docker. I want to send this file to the client (frontend). I specify that the backend and frontend are in Docker containers.
The goal is to create the pdf file then send the file to Angular client. While I'm using docker, It seem a bit complicated.

How can I proceed?

Here the controller code

```
const Utils = require("../helpers/createPDF");

// Local functions
module.exports.generatePDF = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    Utils.generatePDF().then((filePath) => {
      const file = JSON.stringify(filePath);
      const path = file.split(",")[1];
      res.status(200).json({ filePath: path });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};
```

Then the helper fonction

```
const PdfMake = require("pdfmake");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

module.exports.generatePDF = async (data) => {
  const fonts = {
    Roboto: {
      normal: path.join(__dirname, "../fonts/calibri-regular.ttf"),
      bold: path.join(__dirname, "../fonts/calibri-bold.ttf"),
      italics: path.join(__dirname, "../fonts/calibri-italic.ttf"),
      bolditalics: path.join(__dirname, "../fonts/calibri-bold-italic.ttf"),
    },
  };

  const pdfmake = new PdfMake(fonts);

  const entDenomination = "Assol";

  const docDefinition = {
    content: [
      {
        text: entDenomination,
        style: "header",
      },
      {
        text: "fdregs",
        style: "header",
      },
    ],
    styles: {
      header: {
        fontSize: 18,
        bold: true,
        background: "red",
        padding: 12,
      },
      subheader: {
        fontSize: 15,
        bold: true,
      },
      quote: {
        italics: true,
      },
      small: {
        fontSize: 8,
      },
    },
  };

  const ressourceFolder = path.join(__dirname, "public/ressources/pdfs");
  const filesSource = path.join(ressourceFolder, "document1.pdf");

  if (!fs.existsSync(ressourceFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(ressourceFolder, { recursive: true });
  }

  const pdfDoc = pdfmake.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition, {});
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filesSource);
  const outputFile = pdfDoc.pipe(writeStream);
  pdfDoc.end();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writeStream.on("finish", () => {
      resolve(outputFile);
    });

    writeStream.on("error", (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
};
```